# SoapFaultClientException: No such operation

Tags: java, spring, web-services

I'm having a coding problem to use webservice using spring-ws-core with spring boot. below the codes used and the WSDL of the service that I intend to consume:
Class Model

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FuncionariosRequest implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    @XmlTransient
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String cpf;
    private String usuarioInformado;
    private String senhaInformada;

    public FuncionariosRequest() {
        super();
    }

    public FuncionariosRequest(String cpf, String usuarioInformado, String senhaInformada) {
        super();
        this.cpf = cpf;
        this.usuarioInformado = usuarioInformado;
        this.senhaInformada = senhaInformada;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getUsuarioInformado() {
        return usuarioInformado;
    }

    public void setUsuarioInformado(String usuarioInformado) {
        this.usuarioInformado = usuarioInformado;
    }

    public String getSenhaInformada() {
        return senhaInformada;
    }

    public void setSenhaInformada(String senhaInformada) {
        this.senhaInformada = senhaInformada;
    }

}
```

Class Test

```
@Component
public class Principal {

    private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate = new WebServiceTemplate();

    @EventListener 
    private void teste(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        FuncionariosRequest servidor = new FuncionariosRequest();
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setContextPath("br.gov.mt.gestao.ws.model");
        //marshaller.afterPropertiesSet();

        webServiceTemplate.setDefaultUri("http://gestao.com.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws");
        webServiceTemplate.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        webServiceTemplate.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);


        // Código do evento quando for disparado
        webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(servidor);
    }

}
```

file WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://webseap.gestao.mt.gov.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://webseap.gestao.mt.gov.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws" xmlns:intf="http://webseap.gestao.mt.gov.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->

   <wsdl:message name="FuncionariosResponse">

      <wsdl:part name="FuncionariosReturn" type="xsd:string"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="FuncionariosRequest">

      <wsdl:part name="cpf" type="xsd:string"/>

      <wsdl:part name="usuarioInformado" type="xsd:string"/>

      <wsdl:part name="senhaInformada" type="xsd:string"/>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="ws_seap_busca_func_cpf">

      <wsdl:operation name="Funcionarios" parameterOrder="cpf usuarioInformado senhaInformada">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:FuncionariosRequest" name="FuncionariosRequest"/>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:FuncionariosResponse" name="FuncionariosResponse"/>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="ws_seap_busca_func_cpfSoapBinding" type="impl:ws_seap_busca_func_cpf">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="Funcionarios">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="FuncionariosRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://DefaultNamespace" use="encoded"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="FuncionariosResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" namespace="http://webseap.gestao.mt.gov.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws" use="encoded"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="ws_seap_busca_func_cpfService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:ws_seap_busca_func_cpfSoapBinding" name="ws_seap_busca_func_cpf">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://webseap.gestao.mt.gov.br/sec_gestao/ws_seap_busca_func_cpf.jws"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

When I run the application the following error message appears:

```
org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: No such operation 'funcionariosRequest'
    at org.springframework.ws.soap.client.core.SoapFaultMessageResolver.resolveFault(SoapFaultMessageResolver.java:38) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleFault(WebServiceTemplate.java:830) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:624) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:383) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:373) ~[spring-ws-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at br.gov.mt.gestao.ws.Principal.teste(Principal.java:31) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:180) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:400) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:354) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.running(EventPublishingRunListener.java:103) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.running(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:78) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:349) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at br.gov.mt.gestao.ws.FrapsWsApplication.main(FrapsWsApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

I would like to ask for help to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Somewhere in your code are you calling funcionariosResponse instead of FuncionariosResponse (note the upper case "F") - if you're not calling it anywhere, is it listed in any annotations or other things with a lowercase "F" - javas case sensitive so could be your problem?

Comment: Yes, but as I call the method the code is just that. The framework itself already understands how the beginning of the method begins with lowercase letters. Would you like to change the name of the operation to call the service?

Comment: If somewhere in your code the methods "funcionariosResponse" and not "FuncionariosResponse" and you also see a "funcionariosRequest" instead of "FuncionariosRequest" - it's likely not that, but you might try changing it just in case it solves your problem - I've had problems with JAX-B reading XSD's and creating the class name with the wrong case before.  Unlikely for you but worth a try.  Be sure to back up everything prior to any tweaks unless you keep track of all your changes.  And note, I don't use Spring (yet) - so I'm just trying to guide you based on your error :-)